# Перевод из datenum (matlab) в datetime (python) без потери точности

Tags: python, matlab

Имеется .mat файл с datenum значениями (например 735724.3229166666, 735725.6756944444 и т.д.).

Моя цель перевести это в datetime формат без потери точности в питоне, другими словами все должно работать так же точно как если бы это делалось в матлабе.

Я смог найти такие решения:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965740/converting-matlabs-datenum-format-to-python

Но никакие из них недостаточно точны для моего случая.

Например функции на основании ответов из ссылки выше:

```py
def datenum_to_datetime1(datenum):

    days = datenum % 1
    return datetime.fromordinal(int(datenum)) \
           + timedelta(days=days) \
           - timedelta(days=366)

def datenum_to_datetime2(datenum):

    days = np.float_(datenum) % 1
    return datetime.fromordinal(int(datenum)) \
           + timedelta(days=days) \
           - timedelta(days=366)

def datenum_to_datetime3(datenum):

    return pd.to_datetime(datenum-719529, unit='D')

def datenum_to_datetime4(datenum):

    origin = np.datetime64('0000-01-01', 'D') - np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    date = datenum * np.timedelta64(1, 'D') + origin
    return date
```

Дают на 735724.3229166666 такие ответы:

- 2014-05-05 07:44:59.999997
- 2014-05-05 07:44:59.999997
- 2014-05-05 07:45:00.000028800
- 2014-05-05

Третья опция самая близкая к тому чтобы было на матлабе, но все равно недостаточно точна. Можно ли как-то это реализовать на питоне?

Comment: *>>Дают на 735724.3229166666 такие ответы: ...* - А какой должен быть?

Comment: @Михаил Муругов В поле минуты должно быть точно 00. Я не могу установить себе матлаб, с октавом проблемы. Н я точно знаю что на этом примере в поле минуты будет 00